# Magento 2: Translation in JavaScript don't work

Tags: magento2, javascript

I try to translate the next line and this don't show changes:

```
if (pending > 0) {
    $('#wrapper-freeshipping_alert > p').text($.mage.__('You need %1 more for free shipping').replace('%1', priceUtils.formatPrice(pending, quote.getPriceFormat())));
    $('#wrapper-freeshipping_alert').fadeIn();
}
```

In the same extension i have the next files with the translation:

**en_US.csv:**

> "You need %1 more for free shipping","You need %1 more for free shipping"

**es_ES.csv:**

> "You need %1 more for free shipping","Te faltan %1 para portes gratuitos"